# Digital Potentiometer LTSpice Model

Tags: ltspice, simulation, modeling, digital-potentiometer

I'm looking to simulate a circuit in LTSpice which uses a U/D-style digital potentiometer like the Analog Devices AD5220. Is there an existing component model with this type of functionality?
If not, what are other methods I could use to model a pulse-controlled variable resistor in LTSpice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a behavioural resistor approach with one of `int()`, `round()`, `ceil()`, or `floor()`, but you should take care of the discontinuities, to avoid `.TRAN` hiccups:

[image: "digital" pot]

To show that you can have any kind of variation, I've added the `f(x)` definition, but note that, while the function is f(0)=0 and f(1)=1, the extremes will not play nice with the solver, so I've made sure that the steps are N-1, with an offset of 0.5/N. The `Rpar, Cpar` form a time constant for a sufficiently small variation, but enough so that the discontinuities are taken care of, while `tripdv, tripdt` tell the solver to be thorough whithin a change of `tripdv` V / `tripdt` s, and discard the tight timestep elsewhere (e.g. try to preserve the edges while not encumbering the simulation). The `T` is just to give you an idea for the duration of the controlling voltage: since `f(x)` is meant to be used within the interval [0,1], if you simulate it for `T` seconds then you need to adjust its period.

Now, you're saying that you want a "*pulse controlled*" resistor. If you mean that you want to implement a whole "digital" protocol, sure, your time, your money, but I'd go for a behavioural approach: what you're reall after is the *behaviour* of the variable potentiometer to such a discretized approach -- the protocol is just part of the "details". For this, though, you could add a bit of complication with a [counter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/603970/95619), or even make a digital counter with `[Digital]/dflop` and then a DAC (behavioural or not) but, personally, I fail to see the relevance. Your choice.

Comment: Just to be clear: the only reason why I've added a "staircase" coltage was to show that the result can have discrete values, otherwise it may well be a linear control voltage, as well.